# Passing the value of a clicked element in a child component into a button in a parent component in react via state lifting not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components, a parent component and a child component. This child component is inside the parent component. Inside the child component, there's a tag that when it is clicked, a value is been stored in a separate state, Now when a button inside the parent component is clicked, the value that was stored inside a state in the child component should be printed to the console.

```
// import Checboxtest from "./Checkboxtest";
import "./styles.css";

const Child = ({ showresult, click }) => {
  const [clickedvalue, setClickedValue] = useState("");


  const ItemClicked = (e) => {
    setClickedValue("Yes");
    console.log(clickedvalue);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Checkbox Value </h1>

      <span onClick={ItemClicked}>
        <input type="checkbox" /> clik me
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function Parent() {
  const [clickedvalue, setClickedValue] = useState("");
  
  return (
    
    <div className="App">
      
      <button
        onClick={()=>{console.log(clickedvalue)}}
      >
        See checkbox value
      </button>
      <Child setClickedValue={setClickedValue}  />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `Child` never uses `setClickedValue` prop, it uses its own `setClickedValue` state update function. `Child` is also not passed `showresult` or `click` props. It's unclear what you are expecting the behavior to be.

Comment: I want the button in the parent component to print to the console the value of the child component that was clicked. in this situation, when the checkbox in the child component is clicked, it stores the value in a state and when the button in the parent componnet is clicked, we get the value in the console @DrewReese or how can i get the child to use the setclickedvalue props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

`Child` never uses `setClickedValue` prop, it uses its own `setClickedValue` state update function. `Child` is also not passed `showresult` or `click` props.

## Solution

Keep the state in the parent component and pass down the state updater function to the child. When the checkbox in the child is clicked, call the passed callback and pass the new value back to the parent.

```
const Child = ({ setClickedValue }) => {
  const itemClicked = (e) => {
    setClickedValue("Yes");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Checkbox Value </h1>

      <span onClick={itemClicked}>
        <input type="checkbox" /> 
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function Parent() {
  const [clickedValue, setClickedValue] = useState("");
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => { console.log(clickedValue); }}
      >
        See checkbox value
      </button>
      <Child setClickedValue={setClickedValue}  />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
const Child = ({ setClickedValue }) => {
  const itemClicked = (e) => {
    setClickedValue("Yes");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Checkbox Value </h1>

      <span onClick={itemClicked}>
        <input type="checkbox" /> 
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

function Parent() {
  const [clickedValue, setClickedValue] = React.useState("");
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => { console.log(clickedValue); }}
      >
        See checkbox value
      </button>
      <Child setClickedValue={setClickedValue}  />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Take one state like counter tops n parent component and pass it to child component and on change of it use useEffect and console child state on change of that state

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(<child component state here>) 
}, [props.counter])
```

Or if you want to pass that child component value to parent component you can do it like

```
<Child setParentState={setParentState} />

<ChildButton onClick={() => props.setParentState(<value here>) }
```